# Angular ng serve --host local ip suddenly doesn't work with my Mac

Tags: localhost, angular-cli, macos-catalina

I am using

- Mac Catalina 10.15.7
- Angular 11

I used to accessing to my local network(local machine) with my Android mobile phone with

```
ng serve --host 192.168.31.65
```

I had accessed with my mobile to local machine many times. It WORKED many times correctly for long.

But suddenly it doesn't work.

The command works well.

[image]

[image]

I tried with different laptops and two different mobile phones and they works well. So it is not a problem of codes and mobile phones.

My conclusion is that it is a problem of my local machine.

So I checked my firewall as below.

[image]

But I can't deactivate the firewall because of admin settings.

Summary

- It worked well for long but suddenly didn't.
- I tested with multiple different mobile phones but doesn't work, either.
- But it works well if I use same mobile phones with different local machine(Window laptop)

What should I do now?

Comment: Deactivate firewall, find who’s admin… then find out if that’s the case, if not then could be router level problem

Comment: @waseemrakab Thanks. If it is a router level problem, what are the cases I should look at?